# Calling a binary from C (whilst sharing file descriptors)

Tags: c, process, clone, fork, system-calls

I'm playing around with sycalls, and have just written codes along the lines of

```
/* Clone the process and launch Something */
child_stack = (void *) malloc(max_memory);
args = malloc(2 * sizeof (int **));

args[0] = in_socket_fds;
args[1] = out_socket_fds;

clone(foo, child_stack + max_memory ,CLONE_FILES|CLONE_VM|CLONE_IO|CLONE_FS, (void *) args);

wait();
```

where the foo function is :

```
    int foo(int** args) {
     fprintf(stderr, "Hello world %d %d", args[0][0], ags[1][0]);
     _exit(0);
    }
```

What I'd really like to do is call a binary from the foo function.

```
    int foo(int** args) {
     system(start program foo)
     _exit(0);
    }
```

This binary should share the same file descriptor table (hence the use of clone previously). The code above is incorrect, since I don't think system allows to share the file descriptor table. ( I don't want copies of the fds, I really want to be able to read/write them) These fds are sockets.

```
    int foo(int** args) {
     system(start program foo)
     _exit(0);
    }
```

How can I make the clone command call a binary rather than a function? (is this even possible), or use the system call whilst sharing file descriptors?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go for `fork()` / `execlp()` instead of `clone()` / `system()`. A forked child inherits the file descriptors from the parent, and `execlp()` (or its relatives) allow you to load a different executable in the child.

You probably *could* `exec*()` in the function called by `clone()` (see comments), but in this case the `fork()` semantics are much simpler.

Comment: I was under the impression that fork inherited copies of the file descriptors, as opposed to clone who actively shared the table

Comment: @user1018513 : After fork() call, your socket file descriptors are usable also in the child. So any table sharing is not needed.

Comment: @user1018513: You could use `clone()` to create a process executing a function, which *in turn* calls `execlp()` (or one of its relatives). However, in this case `fork()` is the easier option. The documentation of `clone()` also leaves me scratching my head quite a bit about how it could / would cooperate with `exec*()`...

Comment: Thanks, yes, I'd misunderstood how excelp() worked (I thought the fork call happened within the excel). I just used clone followed by exec as you suggested (as I need the child to close the fd I can't just use fork). Thank you.

Comment: @user1018513: Erm... a child can close fd's inherited through the fork() alright...?!?

Comment: Yes but it will remain open in the parent. (well at least that's what I've always thought)

Comment: @user1018513: Yes... unless the parent closes the fd too, which you can or need not do as desired. Sorry, I don't see the problem?

Comment: Sorry I was just saying why I needed clone rather than fork (User1).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13940/discussion-between-devsolar-and-user1018513)